# Pysaprk trying to save a table, getting 403 from AWs s3

Tags: python, dataframe, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to save a Pyspark DF to s3 and getting 403:
I am trying to understand if the issue if coming from the code side or from settings inside the AWS.

This is the error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> o87.saveAsTable. : java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
> s3a://shay-test-bucket/_delta_log: getFileStatus on
> s3a://shay-test-bucket/_delta_log:
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service:
> Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID:
> 2Y4EWPC0WM1MW02E; S3 Extended Request ID:
> ruRAYWkPXzvM29htY10aKa4Ah4XXmawmaPVEMXFTxr0wHHT5n+wVFhkQstgIErz7pxFF8hmdQI0=;
> Proxy: webproxy.com), S3 Extended Request ID:
> ruRAYWkPXzvM29htY10aKa4Ah4XXmawmaPVEMXFTxr0wHHT5n+wVFhkQstgIErz7pxFF8hmdQI0=:403
> Forbidden     at
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:306)
> at
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:293)
> at
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
> at
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135)
> at
> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2410)
> at
> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2380)
> at
> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
> at
> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
> at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)     at
> com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4789)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.getDeltaLogFromCache$1(DeltaLog.scala:801)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.apply(DeltaLog.scala:811)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.apply(DeltaLog.scala:715)    at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.forTable(DeltaLog.scala:653)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog.$anonfun$createDeltaTable$8(DeltaCatalog.scala:152)
> at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)   at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog.$anonfun$createDeltaTable$1(DeltaCatalog.scala:150)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile(DeltaLogging.scala:140)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile$(DeltaLogging.scala:138)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog.recordFrameProfile(DeltaCatalog.scala:57)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$delta$catalog$DeltaCatalog$$createDeltaTable(DeltaCatalog.scala:87)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog$StagedDeltaTableV2.$anonfun$commitStagedChanges$1(DeltaCatalog.scala:489)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile(DeltaLogging.scala:140)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile$(DeltaLogging.scala:138)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog.recordFrameProfile(DeltaCatalog.scala:57)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog$StagedDeltaTableV2.commitStagedChanges(DeltaCatalog.scala:451)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.TableWriteExecHelper.$anonfun$writeToTable$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:603)
> at
> org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1563)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.TableWriteExecHelper.writeToTable(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:587)    at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.TableWriteExecHelper.writeToTable$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:582)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AtomicReplaceTableAsSelectExec.writeToTable(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:202)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AtomicReplaceTableAsSelectExec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:236)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:49)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:118)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:195)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:103)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:104)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:488)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:133)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:856)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:633)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:567)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)    at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
> at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

This is the dataframe save mode

```
        df.write.format("delta").mode('overwrite').saveAsTable("table1", path=f"s3a://{bucket.name}/")
```

this is the initiation of the hadoop pyspark

```
        return (
            SparkConf()
            .setAppName("MY_APP")
            .set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
            .set("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
            .set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider,"
                                                    "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider,"
                                                    "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider")
            .set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key)
            .set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)
            .set("fs.s3a.secret.token", token)
            .set("fs.s3a.endpoint", end_point)
            .set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
        )
```

Comment: HTTP 403 generally means that the credentials are invalid; have you double-checked that?

Comment: I did, it's the same credentials I am using to connect to the boto3